# Specify optional PathParam

Tags: rest, jax-rs, restful-architecture

We have an existing REST API and I want to include an additional optional parameter without doing any other major changes.

**This works today :**

```
@Path("SomeRecommendation/param1={param1}&param2={param2}")  
public String myMethod(  
@PathParam("param1") String param1,  
@PathParam("param2") String param2)
```

**What I want is something like this in a backwards compatible way so that both the following URLs work:**
URL1 : SomeRecommendation/param1=1&param2=2
OR
URL2 : SomeRecommendation/param1=1&param2=2&param3=3
So that existing clients using URL1 do not need to start passing param3 all of a sudden
and new clients are able to pass param3

```
@Path("SomeRecommendation/param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}")
public String myMethod(  
@PathParam("param1") String param1,  
@PathParam("param2") String param2,  
@PathParam("param3") String param3)
```

Anyone solved something similar?
Assume that we can't change from PathParam to QueryParam here.

Comment: This is pretty unclear...

Comment: my bad, fixed the question.

Comment: _" Assume that we can't change from PathParam to QueryParam here."_. Why can't you change something that is wrong to make it right? Make an argument. It makes no sense at all what you're trying to do and the reason you are giving, because to the outside world, whether you use `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam`, it's all the same. The client has no idea.

Comment: There are few things associated with QueryParam which don't work wrt to some framework being used. Can't share more details at this forum and hence asked for help on stack overflow by providing an assumption.
If its not possible then its ok, I would figure some other way out by creating new version of the library/service but at this point if you have some suggestion with given constraint, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but is there any reason not to just have both paths as separate methods? Give the second one a slightly different name, like:

```
@Path("SomeRecommendation/param1={param1}&param2={param2}")  
public String myMethod(  
        @PathParam("param1") String param1,  
        @PathParam("param2") String param2)

@Path("SomeRecommendation/param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}")
public String myNewMethod(  
        @PathParam("param1") String param1,  
        @PathParam("param2") String param2,  
        @PathParam("param3") String param3)
```

Since either URL will have an exact path match, the correct method should be called.

Using path params for this instead of query params is *highly* dubious.

Comment: Thanks Eric, am keeping this as backup option if there is no other way.